# How to Display UPI Payment Status ("Success" or "Failure") from any UPI app in my website?

Tags: php, node.js, next.js, payment, upi

I am developing a website with next.js where I have to detect whether the user has successfully paid the amount or not. I use the standard link: upi://pay and that works (as I have a merchant account and a merchant ID) but I can't detect whether the payment is successful or not.

Does anyone know how to proceed with that. There are some guys who I think, achieved this using PHP. I think it's possible with deeplinking but I don't know how.

Comment: you have to set callback url for each payment

Comment: I think callback url is deprecated now. Does it still work. If so, please explain in a little details as I am complete newbie.